# How to handle terraform property password that the server encrypts

Tags: terraform

I am working on an integration and I seem to have an impossible situation to manage:

Some resources are created with passwords:

```json
{
   "username" : "joe",
   "password" : "MyPassword"
}
```

and this is what gets submitted to the server, but, when I do a GET, I get:

```json
{
   "username" : "joe",
   "password" : "JE2cpXUfyXF7S5yif6z6FXTeTo8bLSozvDNk7iZSapiEkoh4vg"
}
```

It's not **hashed** it's **encrypted** - So, without the key, I can't reproduce this.

The trick is that our terraform users want to create these resources and manage them in TF (with an initial password). I mean, it seems to me that management of username/password simply isn't possible.

Maybe I can override the `DiffSuppressFunc` and have something like:

```
if old starts with `JA...` then directly compare them. But if old is foo... then screw it, they are equal??
```

No clue how to handle this

### More details

This is actually a password managed and encrypted server side on an Artifactory instance - so, password decryption would mean somehow getting it and there is simply no way I can assume the instance admin will give this to anyone. It's in a flat file server side.

I can, I suppose, add a field for it and if, by chance, said TF user can get the encryption key, I can make use of it.

Comment: What resources? Password for what? Some services have dedicated tools for management of passwords, e.g. AWS Secret Manager, Hashicorp Vault, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to ask for more information too, there are many ways to handle it. You can use services as Marcin said, you can use a .tfvars file with the passwords and encrypted with `git-crypt` for example..

Comment: Updated. Hope that helps